# Extract the minor matrix from a 3x3 based on input i,j

Tags: fortran, matrix-multiplication

For a given 3x3 matrix, for example:
A = [3 1 -4 ; 2 5 6 ; 1 4 8]

If I need the minor matrix for entry (1,2)
Minor = [2 6 ; 1 8]

I already wrote a program to read in the matrix from a text file, and I am supposed to write a subroutine to extract the minor matrix from the main matrix A based on the user inputs for i,j. I am very new to Fortran and have no clue how to do that. I made some very desperate attempts but I am sure there is a cleaner way to do that.

I got so desperate I wrote 9 if functions for each possible combination of i and j but that clearly is not a smart way for doing this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In your example `minor(1,2)` is `a([2,3],[1,3])` (or `a(2:3,1:3:2)` but this expression is probably less useful immediately).  Now read about Fortran's *vector subscripts*  and *array sections* in your favourite tutorial, or even search for Qs and As here on SO.

Comment: You are absolutely right Albert, I read the 'How to Ask' and now realize my post wasn't ideal. Sorry newbie here :)

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is, as @HighPerformanceMark said in the comment, with vector subscripts. You can declare an array with the rows you want to keep, and the same for columns, and pass them as indices to your matrix. Like this:

```
function minor(matrix, i, j)
  integer, intent(in) :: matrix(:,:), i, j
  integer :: minor(size(matrix, 1) - 1, size(matrix, 2) - 1)
  integer :: rows(size(matrix, 1) - 1), cols(size(matrix, 2) - 1), k

  rows = [(k, k = 1, i - 1), (k, k = i + 1, size(rows))]
  cols = [(k, k = 1, j - 1), (k, k = j + 1, size(cols))]
  minor = matrix(rows, cols)
end
```

(I didn't test it yet, so tell me if there is any error)

Another option would be constructing a new matrix from 4 assignments, one for each quadrant of the result (limited by the excluded row/column).

I like the first option more because it is more scalable. You could easily extend the function to remove multiple rows/columns by passing arrays as arguments, or adapt it to work on higher dimensions.

Comment: Brilliant, I wasn't able to get your specific function to compile properly but it's probably due to my inexperience. However the concept worked great, I created a subroutine that creates rows and cols (wasn't able to get a function to return a Matrix, will look into that later today)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *ac-implied-do* and `RESHAPE` to construct a mask of the parts of the matrix you want to preserve and then zap the rest with `pack` and reassemble with `RESHAPE`.

```
program minor
   implicit none
   integer A(3,3)
   integer, allocatable :: B(:,:)
   character(20) fmt
   integer i, j
   A = reshape([ &
       3,  1, -4, &
       2,  5,  6, &
       1,  4,  8], &
      shape(A), order = [2,1])
   write(fmt,'(*(g0))') '(a/',size(A,2),'(i3))'
   write(*,fmt) 'A =',transpose(A)
   B = reshape(pack(A,reshape([((all([i,j]/=[1,2]),i=1,size(A,1)), &
      j=1,size(A,2))],shape(A))),shape(A)-1)
   write(fmt,'(*(g0))') '(a/',size(B,2),'(i3))'
   write(*,fmt) 'B =',transpose(B)
end program minor
```

Output:

```
A =
  3  1 -4
  2  5  6
  1  4  8
B =
  2  6
  1  8
```